# Making responsive website: Form overlaps

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I manage to do everything responsive except for my form to overlap, causing to have me scroll horizontally.

[(Click here) Form looks normal, until...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1L0X.jpg)

when I navigated this page, somehow, it overlaped..

[(Click here) My page is screwed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuWRo.jpg)

I am using a global .css here to create the site, because somehow I am
forbidden to add/edit/delete html codes.

I cannot change the tr and body of the table because the other page would mess up.

My only problem is this page that unexpectedly scrolls horizontally.

I dunno what's the problem here..help me

my table is inside a form. My code is...

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    form {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  max-height: 500px;
  margin:0 auto;
 }
 table, table td, table th {
  display: block;
  width: inherit;
  text-align: left;
 }  
}
```

Comment: please copy your html and css and create a demo on jsfiddle, then the problem is better visible and testable - you'll get better help then

Comment: you have a div that is larger then the width of the viewport that is making you horizontal scroll